# Add HttpCookie after OutputStream EndWrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, outputstream, fileoutputstream

i want to add HttpCookie after this code :

```
zipFile.Save(context.Response.OutputStream);
```

how can i do this? any idea?

Comment: yes, i try. and i want after file send to output stream cookie added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to create cookie.

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Name of cookie");
 cookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
 cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10d);
 Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

more details [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.httpcookie.aspx)